# Не могу решить проблему с pymem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymem

Использовал библиотеку [pymem](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem) и столкнулся с такой проблемой

> (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'base_address')

Вот код:

```
import pymem
import pymem.process


pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
print('Process Base Address: {}'.format(pm.process_base_address))
```

Comment: Ошибка означает что у объекта `pm` нет поля `process_base_address`. А почему вы решили что он должен быть? Это из какого-то примера взяли?

Comment: да из примера , и спасибо за ответ

Comment: @gil9red если точнее, тут у объекта `None` нет поля `process_base_address`. Что в общем-то неудивительно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, точно. Не обратил внимания на None, зато у pymem поискал `process_base_address` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
print('Process Base Address: {}'.format(pm.process_base))
```

Похоже, что разработчики pymem обновили код библиотеки, но не отразили обновления в документации.

Comment: @Detsu, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)